# Class instance method call and @property access delegator

Tags: python

I'd like to create a delegator `D` for an existing class `A` instance s.t. method calls and `@property` attribute access to `A` can be mocked in `D`:

```
class D(object):
  def __init__(self, instance_of_A):
    self.instance_of_A = instance_of_A

  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    ...
    def attr_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      print('accessing attribute', attr)
      res = getattr(self.instance_of_A, attr)(*args, **kwargs)
      ...
      return res

    return attr_wrapper
```

While that works for delegating to `A`'s method calls that doesn't work
for `@property` attributes of `A`. What's the best way to make it work?

## EDIT

To clarify, this doesn't work if `A` has a @property attribute:

```
class A(object):
  @property
  def foo():
    return 1
```

## EDIT2

Returning `attr_wrapper` is important since I want to intercept the return
value that call.

Comment: Would be surprising if this code works. You aren't returning attribute value from `__getattr__` but a function to retrieve value. `getattr()` does also read property values from `A`, where exactly is the problem?

Comment: @MichaelButscher The problem is that this doesn't work if `A` has @property attribute (let's say @property def foo(): return 1) since the return value of D(A()).foo would be a function call and not 1.

Comment: Don't return a function at all, just return the attribute. This would work even if the attribute is actually a function in `A`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I need to intercept the return value of that call in the delegator.

Comment: In this case check if the attribute value is `callable()` (or use `inspect` module for further details) and only return function if it is.